# How can I suppress the login dialogue caused by the WWW-Authenticate header?

Tags: http, authentication, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10

When a user is unauthorised to access a page, I send a HTTP 401. Additionally, as required by the [HTTP/1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2), I also send a `WWW-Authenticate` header.

I know of at least 1 case where omitting this header causes an issue: Firebug (the *Net* tab will be empty).

A user can log in with both an email address or a username, and a password. The form is submitted over AJAX, and a JSON response takes care of redirecting the user after successfully logging in, or displaying an error message on failure.

On Windows Phone 8, a custom dialogue is shown when this header is present. It has fields for *User name*, *Password*, and *Domain*. It also has checkboxes for *Show password* and *Remember my password*.
The thing is, this dialogue doesn't work at all with the authentication process of the application.

The value of the header doesn't seem to matter, I've tried with `WWW-Authenticate: form` and `WWW-Authenticate: blah` but I get the dialogue regardless. How can I suppress this while still adhering to the spec?

Comment: `The form is submitted over AJAX` - does that mean you send user/pw via a html form? In that case, you shouldn't use `WWW-Authenticate`, not even a `401` actually, as these are part of the standardized http authentication, which the client uses via the `[Authorization](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.8)` header. But form-based authentication is not standardized, and HTTP doesn't offer you any special support for it.

Comment: @Eugene I guess multiple sources giving the same advice (SO posts, blogs, etc.) doesn't always mean it's correct advice. Is it correct to say that using a custom value for the header results in undefined behaviour? And can you post this as an answer, so I can accept and award the bounty? Thanks!

Comment: @Eugene After reading your comment I found [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/24452/21304), confirming what you wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question and the comments it seems you are doing form-based authentication, but, in order to comply with the HTTP spec, you thought you should return a `401`, and, as that requires to also send the `WWW-Authenticate` header, you added that as well.

The fact of the matter is: **Form-based authentication is non-standard, and you should not use 401 Unauthorized**, which is to be used with standard HTTP authentication. So using a dummy authentication method might help you comply with the letter of the spec in terms of WWW-Authenticate, but you shouldn't be using 401 in the first place.

The [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.2) reads:

> **10.4.2 401 Unauthorized**
>
> The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the request with a suitable Authorization header field.

All this talk about HTTP headers (`WWW-Authenticate` and `Authorization`) makes it clear that this is about giving the client software the information needed to do the standard HTTP authentication (via a dialog in most cases).

Btw providing a custom authentication method in the `WWW-Authenticate` header makes sense when you want to to HTTP authentication, i.e. via the `Authorization` header, but use your own authentication scheme, rather than *basic* or *digest*. This of course requires a client that understands that custom scheme.

So what could you do instead? As form-authentication is non-standard, this is not defined in the specs, but how about redirecting the user to a/the page with the login form using a [`307 Temporary Redirect`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.8), perhaps adding information so you can automatically redirect the user back to the page he wanted to access after verifying the credentials.